# Is there any dependable way to see my web-app on different browsers/platforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Are there any site that allow developers to truly and dependably see how their app/site will look on various devices/platforms/versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.browserstack.com/ or https://saucelabs.com/ is good choice for testing your website on 300+ browser/os combination, but you need to pay for the service if you need serious testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just google the name of what you need for example if you want to test your APP/Website on an IPhone then lookup - 'Iphone simulator for testing' and you'd get something like this - http://iphone4simulator.com/

Same with other browsers/phone.

Be more specific if you're looking for a specific device.

Comment: I've tried that, I was looking for a -DEPENDABLE- representation of how my app will look on an iphone, not a representation of how my app will look on an iphone.  I've tried both the site you requested and the chrome developer tools and they both are false and not dependable.

Answer (score 0):

The latest download of Google Chrome has an emulator-ish type of feature build into the dev tools. You can select from a super wide range of named devices including ipads and iphones (and theire respective versions). I use it daily, you should check it out.

Comment: I used that and it's bs.  I just made a web app that looked totally fine in the developer tools iphone and then when I deployed it, it simply -did-not-work on an iphone.  That's exactly why I'm here.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems like you need a little bit of port forwarding magic. You should really be more descriptive in your question. What type of app architecture are you using? Does it emulate a port in your local host? If so then shis is a shell question and you could do some really risky ssh action and expose a live port to access through your iDevice. This is the easies way that I have come across to get an actual live version of what I am building through any internet connected device.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware about browsers, in chrome can open developer too(press F12).On right top of developer tool , u can see a icon call show drawer , click on it , than can select simulate tab where there will be a checkbox , which can be selected to allow simulate on other devices I.e tablets, mobiles. 
Now desired devices can be selected from the dropdown and can be tested.

Comment: I did that and it was an inaccurate representation of an iphone.  When I delopyed my page and viewed it in my iphone it simply did not look the way it did in the browser tools.

Comment: Did u select iPhone in devices?

Comment: Yes, my exact iphone version and it worked in the developer tools and did not work on my iphone.  it really pissed me off because now I have to restart my whole project from scratch because I wasted time thinking this was a dependable way to view my app on an iphone.